# Response times from PostMan scripts

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, postman

Is there a simple way to capture the Response times for the requests and responses in a PostMan script?

I am trying to do the following by creating a Collection and then in the Tests, writing the following script to capture and put the value in an Environment variable:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("MyURLRequest", (responseTime));
```

This provides me the value in the Environment variable, but I need to specifically go there everytime to check the time.

The other way I have tried is to use the 'Runner' on the collection and get the response times from the "totalRequestTime" value in the exported results. But as I am running ~50 requests, it becomes hard to capture the same for each individual request.

Has anyone tried this earlier and been able to get a better way to capture and export a response time value for each request sent out?

Comment: Not sure if this helps you or not, but if you want to record performance stats from an execution of a Postman collection, we have a performance test/load test tool called [k6](https://k6.io) which reports lots of performance stats and for which there is a [Postman-to-k6](https://github.com/loadimpact/postman-to-k6) converter available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the built-in `pm.response.responseTime` function to get the times.

Add it to a `console.log(pm.response.responseTime)` in a test, to try it out or assign this to an env/global variable.

You could even (it's a little bit over kill though) do this:

[image: Response Times]

If you didn't want it in each test, this could be added to the collection. On the latest version, press edit on the collection to see the options.

Answer (score 3):

```
pm.test("Response time is less than 200ms", () => {
 pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(200);
});
```

Above [scriipt](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/) is to test the response time, to print response time you can do something like this

```
pm.test("Response time is less than 200ms which is "+pm.response.responseTime, () => {
 pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(200);
});
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I could achieve this on Newman using below code:

```
"event": [
    {
    "listen": "test",
    "script": {
        "id": "aaaaaaaa-1111-4444-aaaa-000000011111",
        "exec": [                   
                  "var rtm = pm.response.responseTime",
                  "var rts = rtm/1000",

                  "pm.test(\"Check response time and Status\", function () {",
                  "pm.response.to.have.status(200);",

                  "console.log(\"Response time in mili seconds\" , rtm);",
                  "console.log(\"Response time in seconds\" , rts);",
                   "});"    
                ]
            }
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following script in collection Tests, update `desiredIterationsCount` based on number of iterations you want to run, this can also be stored as a global variable

```
// we are running 10 iterations so this will reset counters for the nex run
var desiredIterationsCount = 10

var responseTime = pm.response.responseTime
var totalResponseTime = (typeof pm.collectionVariables.get("totalResponseTime") === 'undefined') ? 0 : pm.collectionVariables.get("totalResponseTime");
var iterationsCount = (typeof pm.collectionVariables.get("iterationsCount") === 'undefined') ? 0 : pm.collectionVariables.get("iterationsCount");
var maxResponseTime = (typeof pm.collectionVariables.get("maxResponseTime") === 'undefined') ? null : pm.collectionVariables.get("maxResponseTime");
var minResponseTime = (typeof pm.collectionVariables.get("minResponseTime") === 'undefined') ? null : pm.collectionVariables.get("minResponseTime");

iterationsCount++
if(iterationsCount > desiredIterationsCount) {
    iterationsCount = 1
    totalResponseTime = 0
    maxResponseTime = null
    minResponseTime = null
}

if(maxResponseTime == null || responseTime > maxResponseTime) {
    maxResponseTime = responseTime
    pm.collectionVariables.set("maxResponseTime", maxResponseTime)
}

if(minResponseTime == null || responseTime < minResponseTime) {
    minResponseTime = responseTime
    pm.collectionVariables.set("minResponseTime", minResponseTime)
}

totalResponseTime = totalResponseTime + responseTime
pm.collectionVariables.set("totalResponseTime", totalResponseTime)
pm.collectionVariables.set("iterationsCount", iterationsCount)

if(iterationsCount === desiredIterationsCount) {
    console.log("iterationsCount: ", iterationsCount)
    console.log("avgResponseTime: ", totalResponseTime/iterationsCount)
    console.log("maxResponseTime: ", maxResponseTime)
    console.log("minResponseTime: ", minResponseTime)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var time=pm.response.responseTime
pm.test('Set Filter up to 3 month and check the Response time in millisecond(1 Sec =1000 millisecond):-> ' +time ,()=>
pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.eql(200));
```

Above Code will give you response time in millisecond.